# Best way of receiving frames in a thread in C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, threadpool, hololens

I am facing problem with receiving frames from the HoloLens. Basically I am capturing frame and sending it to the server using one socket connection. I used am sending frame to server when ever HoloLens get the frame using `Task.Run(#send to server call)` but the problem is it works fine at the start but then the frame per second (FPS) got decrease to zero and the problem I found is it basically made too many threads and there create a bottleneck (that's what I figured out) so now what I did was instead of using `Task.Run(#send to server call)` I used `Parallel.Invoke(#send to server call)`, but it gives low FPS and the reason for it I found is that, while it working on this invoke call there are some frame arrived which result in low FPS. I also tried async/await method but still same bottleneck happened and FPS decrease to zero. I also tried to use cancelation token but it didn't work too. Here is the function which call whenever frame arrives at HoloLens.

```
    private void ColorFrameReader_FrameArrivedAsync(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
    {
        var frame = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame();
        if (frame != null)
        {
            SoftwareBitmap originalBitmap = null;
            var inputBitmap = frame.VideoMediaFrame?.SoftwareBitmap;
            if (inputBitmap != null)
            {
                // The XAML Image control can only display images in BRGA8 format with premultiplied or no alpha
                // The frame reader as configured in this sample gives BGRA8 with straight alpha, so need to convert it
                originalBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(inputBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);                 
                SoftwareBitmap outputBitmap = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, originalBitmap.PixelWidth, originalBitmap.PixelHeight, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

                //this thread goes to the c++ code and start the TCP communication                
                //var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); _helper.Connect(originalBitmap); }, cts.Token);
                
                ab_func(originalBitmap);
                                                                            
               //System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(_helper.Connect(originalBitmap)));
                //Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync                    
                //Parallel.Invoke(() => _helper.Connect(originalBitmap));
                //task.Start();
            }

            Interlocked.Increment(ref _frameCount);
        }
    }

    async void ab_func(SoftwareBitmap fr)
    {
       await Task.Run(() => { _helper.Connect(fr); });
    }
```

Here are some further information regarding connect method of C++ file. `_helper` is basically the object of that C++ class.

```
void OpenCVHelper::Connect(SoftwareBitmap^ input)
{
  Mat inputMat, outputMat;
  if (!(TryConvert(input)))
  {
      return;
  }
int imgSize = GlobalMat.total() * GlobalMat.elemSize();
//m_OutStream << "GlobalMat.total()  " << GlobalMat.total();
//m_OutStream << "GlobalMat.total()  " << GlobalMat.elemSize();
int i = 1;
//m_OutStream << "i value is  \n"<<i;
auto t0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto nanosec = t0.time_since_epoch();


if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    //printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    //m_OutStream << "Unable to connect to server! 2\n" << WSAGetLastError();
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}
uchar* iptr = GlobalMat.data;
t0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
nanosec = t0.time_since_epoch();
m_OutStream << "timestamp before sending of frame " << i++ << " = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(nanosec).count() << std::endl;


//send the frame to the server
if ((bytes = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)iptr, imgSize, 0)) < 0) {
    //m_OutStream << "bytes = " << bytes << std::endl;
    m_OutStream << "problem 2 ! \n";
    //break;
}

return;
}
```

And Here is the debug screenshot which I said that it made too many threads and create bottleneck. [image: Debug screenshot]

Comment: What is _helper and what does the Connect method signature look like? If the API is blocking, there's not much you can do from async/await perspective. The thread becomes blocked outside of your code. You could employ different approaches such as buffering the frames and sending them in batches in a single thread but that could potentially lead to long waits and result in out of memory conditions. You could also employ limited number of threads for the processing so that you have higher throughput without running out of threads.

Comment: You have a TCP connection where every datagram gets an ACK.  When the ACKs slow down the data transfer rate also slows down.  Doing a parallel connection does not solve the issue.  With TCP when the ACKS are not received the datagram gets sent up to 3 times at 5 seconds apart which adds more traffic and slows down connection even more due to added data being sent.  Usually problem is at server not ack fast enough.  You may have a slow network (or overloaded) which delay traffic through routers.  I usually test network using ping (from cmd.exe) with large messages : ping IP -t -l 65500

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek regarding your second solution how can I limit the number of thread? I try to use Threadpool but it gives error that system.threading does not have this namespace or method. ( Basically I am new C# programming) sorry for that much basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the bottleneck is sending frames over the network.  Tasks, `System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, and `Parallel.Invoke` all use the threadpool.  Sending frames over TCP is clearly slow and new tasks are queued on the thread pool faster than threads are becoming free again, and you quickly exhaust the thread pool.

A better approach would be to queue all frames in a local queue `ConcurrentQueue<t>`, and have a few threads consume the queue and send the frames to the server.  In this way, you will be able to read frames faster from the device (higher FPS).  The downside is that after you stop receiving frames, you will still have to wait for all frames to be sent to the server.